# Facebook API FB.ui feed reporting error - how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, facebook, feed

My code looks like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></Script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    FB.ui(
   {
       method: 'feed',
       name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
       link: 'http://www.dynacal.com/default.aspx?OrgID=407&PageType=EDetail&EDID=1973',
       picture: 'http://www.dynacal.com/File/GetFile.aspx?Logo=5942',
       caption: '6:30AM - 07:45AM',
       description: 'Boys 7th Grade Basketball Practice',
       message: 'Facebook Dialogs are easy!'
   },
   function (response) {
       if (response && response.post_id) {
           alert('Post was published.');
       } else {
           alert('Post was not published.');
       }
   }
 );
</Script>
```

This is the result.
An error occurred. Please try again later.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You did not specifiy your App ID anywhere, that´s most likely the main reason for the error. Better use the asynchronous version of the JavaScript anyway, for example:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    //SDK loaded, initialize it
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'your-app-id',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.5'
    });

    //important! only after FB.init you can use FB.ui and stuff
};

//load the JavaScript SDK
(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Source (and more information): http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

**Also, you need to call `FB.ui` on user interaction (mouse click), not on page load. Else it will get blocked in some browsers. And there is no `message` parameter.**